# Replace String from MongoDb result using Javascript and Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Okay so for example I have this collection named `"Results"`.

I'll query `Results.find()`;

This will give the value of `{foo: 'hello_world'}`;

and now I want to replace the _ with a " " (white space) using javascript before I return it to the template. Any idea how?

Comment: use http://dochub.io/#javascript/string.replace?

Comment: `Results.find().forEach(function(bar){ bar.foo.replace('_',' ');});` doesn't work. or

`var a = Results.find();
a.replace('_', ' ');`

 doesn't work too

Comment: you can't assign to an iterator variable in a forEach loop, just use a regular for loop instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a transform. You just alter your `Results.find()` to include it as an option.

```
var transform = function(doc) {
    doc.foo = doc.foo.replace(/_/g, ' ');
    return doc;
}

return Results.find({}, {transform: transform} );
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work in your helper:

```
return Results.find().fetch().map(function(res) {
    res.foo = res.foo.replace('_', ' ');
    return res;
});
```